# How to add more then 1 operation per ternary case for jQuery .append($("<option/>", {...})?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding multiple `option` elements to a `select` element using jQuery. Based on the value of `data` the text of an option and whether or not it's disabled is different. The order of adding the option elements to the select element should be chronological since they are delivery options.

Ideally I'd like to add `if-else` statements but that's not working. The conditional ternary operator does work but it only seems to work for a single operation per case.

Example:

The default value for a specific option is '8/1 tussen 14:00-15:00 | €4.95'
If `data.response` is smaller then 0 then it should be '8/1 tussen 14:00-15:00 | Vol' and the option should be disabled. Else it should return the enabled default value for that option.

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
$.each(timeSlotsObj, function(key, value) {
  var option_date = value.split(" ")[0].replace('/', '-'),
      option_slot = value.split(" ")[2];

  $.get("http://<REDACTED>/availability/" + selected_retailer_id + "/" + option_date + "/" + option_slot, function(data) {
    delivery_time_element.append($("<option/>", {
        value: key,
        text: data.response < 1 ? (
          new_value = value.split(' ')
          new_value[4] = 'Vol'
          new_value.join(' ')
        ) : value,
        disabled: data.response < 1 ? true : false
    }));
  });
});
```

But this returns a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` for:

```
new_value[4] = 'Vol'
```

What else could I try?

Comment: As a tip, remove all spaces and newlines from your code (except inside quotes ofc). You'll see those lines need a separator. Spaces / Newlines are not separators in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend moving that logic into a separate function.

```
$.get("http://<REDACTED</availability/" + selected_retailer_id + "/" + option_date + "/" + option_slot, function(data) {
  var vol = function(val) {
    var parts = value.split(' ');
    parts[4] = "Vol";
    return parts.join(' ');
  };
  delivery_time_element.append($("<option/>", {
      value: key,
      text: data.response < 1 ? vol(value) : value,
      disabled: data.response < 1 ? true : false
  }));
});
```

This makes the code much more readable and easier to follow.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a comma after each operation like so:

```
$.get("http://<REDACTED</availability/" + selected_retailer_id + "/" + option_date + "/" + option_slot, function(data) {
  delivery_time_element.append($("<option/>", {
      value: key,
      text: data.response < 1 ? (
        new_value = value.split(' '), // <<<<
        new_value[4] = 'Vol', // <<<<
        new_value.join(' ')
      ) : value,
      disabled: data.response < 1 ? true : false
  }));
});
```

In this case, the last comma-separated value of the parenthesis will be the value to be assigned.

Comment: Commas are most often used by minifiers and the like in order to shorten expressions, but they do have some use in "real" code too - personally my most common use is in `for( i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++)` where I combine two statements into one. The important thing is that the `,` operator evaluates its two operands and returns the second one - or the last one in the case of a chain :)

Comment: @narzero own answered?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi nothing wrong with answering your own question, however this is a simple case of incorrect syntax and should just be closed.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi, I figured this out 10 seconds after posting the question. Seems silly now.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes you are right but withing 10 sec :)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan even simple cases of incorrect syntax are cases every newcommer to jQuery can learn form.

Comment: The best solution to any syntax error is to check the console ;)